# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in solr

Tags: jquery, solr, knockout.js

I am trying to add a new document in the solr server.
My Code

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://192.168.10.113:8080/solr/update/json?commit=true",
            data: { "add": { "doc": { 'id': '19990' } } },
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            crossDomain: true,
            jsonp: 'json.wrf',
            success: function (data) { alert(data); },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            }
        });
```

My Solr server is hosted in different domain so i wrote

```
 dataType: 'jsonp',
 crossDomain: true,
 jsonp: 'json.wrf',
```

to over come from cross domain problem.

Now it is showing **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**  Error 
I searched on Google.
maximum of experts suggested that to check in the html and js code.
I checked its fine.No extra < symbol is there.
[Error Image](http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/3626/myerror.png)

After that i changed the URL from 
http: //192.168.10.113:8080/solr/update/json?commit=true to http: //192.168.10.113:8080/solr/update/xml?commit=true

now its showing error link this

**GET http: //192.168.10.113:8080/solr/update/xml?commit=true&json.wrf=jQuery1710918970147613436_1351693492662&add%5Bdoc%5D%5Bid%5D=19990&_=1351693497692 405 (Method Not Allowed)**

Please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: I'm going to ask the obvious question: Does your server and/or application allow "Post" requests?  After searching on the error, this seems to be the common cause of this error.

Comment: yes,I am fetching data from the server using post request.
Now i am trying to add document into the server.

Comment: I don't think you can send POST data with a JSONP request.. afterall the request is done using an injected `<script>` tag. Also have you seen [this link](http://skipperkongen.dk/2011/01/11/solr-with-jsonp-with-jquery/)? you seem to be missing the 'wt=json' param. Your error seems to indicate that the server is sending back XML (makes sense looking at the url.. and because of the `<` token in the error). with JSONP, the server returns javascript code, not XML/HTML (and not JSON, technically speaking).

Comment: I think while fetching data from the server we have to add 'wt'='json' parameter.
I added the above parameter and its showing same error.
You can see my error image imageshack.us/photo/my-images/195/errormiz.png

Comment: exactly, your image shows that the server is responding with XML, but JSONP requires that the server send back actual JS code. hence the error

Comment: How to overcome from this error??
any way to overcome from this problem :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was showing *Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <* error because the server is sending xml data.

Declare json as input parameter.So I set the server as json,so that this type of error will not occur.

Comment: What do you mean by this?